# I Can't save my logs to a log file in log4j 2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm using Log4j 2 to create a logging system for my game. This is the code from my Log.java file:
    package com.encoded.game.console;

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Log {
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("Encoded Logger");

public static void log(String toLog){
    logger.info(toLog);
}

public static void logWarn(String toWarn){
    logger.warn(toWarn);
}

public static void logErr(String toErr){
    logger.error(toErr);
}

public static void logTrace(String toTrace){
    logger.trace(toTrace);
}

public static void logDebug(String debug){
    logger.debug(debug);
}

public static void logFatal(String fatal){
    logger.fatal(fatal);
}
}
```

and this is my log4j2.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
    <Property name="archive">${log-path}/archive</Property>
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>
            [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
        </pattern>>
      </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
    <File name="File-Appender" fileName="${log-path}/encoded_latest.log" >
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>
            [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>        
  </Appenders>
```

Why is this not outputting to a file? Am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: I believe (not sure...) it is because you are declaring the appender, but you are not using it anywhere

Comment: please add full xml file

Comment: this is the full XML

Answer (score -1):

try with this basic configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration>
        <Properties>
            <Property name="log-path">log</Property>
        </Properties>


    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file-log" fileName="${log-path}/app.log" filePattern="${log-path}/HelloLog4j-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%5p] - %c{1}:%L %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"  modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="[%5p] - %c{1}:%L %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <Root level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
            <appender-ref ref="file-log" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```